# Function within a function in python

Tags: python

I recently came across the idea of defining a function within a function in Python. I have this code and it gives this error:

---

```
def f1(a):
    def f2(x):
       return a+x
    return 2*a
```

---

Error: On calling `f2(5)`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
f2(5)
NameError: name 'f2' is not defined
```

---

I am having some difficulty understanding the way global variables are used across functions or even in recursive calls. I would really appreciate it if someone would point out my mistake and maybe help me along the way. Thanks!!

Comment: Two downvotes? Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Comment: @GraemePerrow: perhaps people feel it shows a lack of research effort (I myself didn't vote on this question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You defined `f2` in the local namespace of `f1` *only*; it is not available globally.

If you want such a nested function to be available at the module level, you'd have to either return it from the function, or define a `global` variable to store it in:

```
def f1(a):
    def f2(x):
       return a+x
    return 2*a, f2
```

then call that as `result, f2 = f1(somevariable_or_literal)`.

The `global` approach is not recommendable (using a `global` rarely is) but would look something like:

```
f2 = None

def f1(a):
    global f2
    def f2_local(x):
         return a+x
    f2 = f2_local
    return 2*a
```

at which point `f2` will be set when you have called `f1`.

Answer (score 7):

`f2` is defined inside `f1`. Therefore, it's scope only extends inside the function `f1`. Outside of that space, the function `f2` doesn't even exist, which is why you're getting the error.

If you were to call `f2` from somewhere inside `f1` after `f2` is defined, it would work.

[Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) has a good explanation of how scope works in Python.